# setting slider for multiple sets of manipulating variable Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, slider

I am working with data and using manipulate function. I have two sets of values in the manipulating variable list which I combine to form a single list. So, the increment which forms the first set won't generate the second set elements of the list. How can I tell slider to specify increments differently for two halves of the manipulating variable? Here is a sample:

I form a manipulating variable set with two different lists:

```
k1 = Flatten[{Range[-1.61, 0, .1], Sort[-Range[-1.61, 0, .1], #1 < #2 &]}];
```

Random data as a function of `k1` elements for the manipulate Plot:

```
data = Table[Table[Sin[k x], {x, 1, 5, .1}], {k, k1}];
```

and finally, Manipulate

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[data[[Position[k1, k][[1, 1]]]], AxesLabel -> {"x", "f"}, 
          BaseStyle -> "Section"], {{k, -1.61, Style["k", 24]}, First[k1], 
          Last[k1], .1, ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
          LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 25}}, AutorunSequencing -> {{1, 10}}]
```

This works for one half of the `k1`'s elements but not for the other as 0.1 won't generate the second half. Is there any If conditon or Piecewise operation to incorporate the second half of the `k1`'s elements?

(Note: This is a data-based question so the function `Sin[k x]` isn't available.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `k1` as the iterator list (instead of `First[k1], Last[k1], .1`) for the contor variable `k` and specify the control as `Manipulator`:

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[data[[Position[k1, k][[1, 1]]]], 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f"}, BaseStyle -> "Section"],
{{k, -1.61, Style["k", 24]}, k1, Manipulator, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> "Labeled", LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 25}}, 
AutorunSequencing -> {{1, 10}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @klgr thanks a lot.Most of the times I get around the technicalities using a different variation but this was kind of bugging me. `Manipulator` is exactly what I was looking for. Anything more with `Manipulator` that can be done such as specifying increment of the slider i.e rather than going through all the values of k1, make slider jump 3 steps at a time?

Comment: @maeinss, you can use `k1[[1;;-1;;3]]` instead of `k1`.

Comment: @Klgr got it, thanks